# Is there a control for a choice with the green arrow icon?

Tags: wpf, user-interface

Is there a control for a choice, with the little green arrow icon?

They look like this:

[image: Action / UAC]

I've already searched through the controls, but I haven't found any. )=

Comment: `Image` control

Comment: No, I don't want an Image, I want the button looking thing. But not a `Button` control.

Comment: 42 facepalms. `<Button><Image/></Button>`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do the round border? (I already know how to do the background gradient)

Comment: I found it, it's in the [Microsoft Windows API Code Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Core/), it's called the `CommandLink` and it's in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a style for your needs.

```
  <!--Default Button-->
  <Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>

            <!--Template-->
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <!--Default border, please dont rename it-->
                <Border x:Name="border" 
                        CornerRadius="2"> <!-- makes rounded corner -->
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter></Style>
```